# nginx subdomain rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx, mod-rewrite

I need a nginx rewrite rule to rewrite from:

`http://some-keyword.example.com` to `www.example.com/keyword.php?keyword=$some-keyword`

while domain without `www` in front still rewrites to `www.example.com` and `www` isn't taken as a keyword.

Please could you help me to solve this problem, how to write these two rules?

Comment: You say rewrite (as in server side, proxy rewrite) but it sounds like you mean redirect? On a redirect the URL visible to the user changes. On a proxy rewrite, it all happens on the server side, invisible to the user.

Comment: I meant rewrite, what users should see is http://keyword.example.com Conny

Answer (score 7):

If you meant redirect, then:

```
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;

  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/keyword.php?keyword=$1 redirect;
}
```

In the case of *rewrite* then simply do

```
server {
  server_name example.com ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;

  rewrite ^ /keyword.php?keyword=$1 break;

#  location /keyword.php {
#    ....
#  }
}
```

Comment: Even if the question was regarding rewrites, your example does not exclude "www" like it should. You need to add a negative lookahead construct for that: ` ^((?!www\.).*)\.example\.com$ `

Comment: The config should be ok without negative lookahead, because Nginx has server search ordering such that full names (www.example.com) go before regexes.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but this solution doesn't seem to be rewriting the host.  In the OP, he requested that the server be handling www.example.com/keyword.php?keyword=$1 when the rules were complete, but this appears to rewrite only the path and query.  Is there a way to rewrite the host internally?  I've only seen examples using redirects and all my experiments have failed.  Thanks.

Comment: You cannot `rewrite` host. But you can proxy to it.

Comment: server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.example\.com$ ;

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite ^/list-c-([0-9]+)-k-(.+)-o-1\.html$ /index.php?module=Default&action=List&c=$1&k=$2&o=1 last;
rewrite ^/list-c-([0-9]+)-k-(.+)-o-1-p-(.+)\.html$ /index.php?module=Default&action=List&c=$1&k=$2&o=1&p=$3 last;
rewrite ^/list-c-([0-9]+)-k-(.+)-o-1-price-(.+)\.html$ /index.php?module=Default&action=List&c=$1&k=$2&o=1&price=$3 last;
rewrite ^/list-c-([0-9]+)-k-(.+)-o-(.+)-p-1\.html$ /index.php?module=Default&action=List&c=$1&k=$2&o=$3&p=1 last;
rewrite ^/list-c-([0-9]+)-k-(.+)-o-(.+)-p-(.+)\.html$ /index.php?module=Default&action=List&c=$1&k=$2&o=$3&p=$4 last;
```

Comment: This does not answer his question. Maybe you answere to the wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible I'd only create 1 server(virtual host) which is the normal `domain.com`/`www.domain.com` and then use the conf to rewrite the rest to them

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    # normal handling for files
}

server {
    server_name ~(?<subdomain>[^\.]*).domain.com;
    location / {
        try_files keyword.php?keyword=$subdomain =404;
    }
}
```

please tell me if I missed something.