# nginx subdomain rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

Yet another nginx rewrite rule question:

How can I do a rewrite from `http://www.*.domain.com` to `http://*.domain.com`?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498712/nginx-subdomain-rewrite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
  set $host_without_www $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1 permanent; # $1 contains '/foo', not 'www.mydomain.com/foo'
}
```

Answer from server fault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/139579/nginx-subdomain-rewrite

Comment: This approach is not recommended nowadays. See [this section on common pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Using_If).

Comment: what is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name ~^www\.(\w+)\.domain\.com$;
  location / {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$1.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this yields a double query string, a request for `/?foo=bar` will redirect to `/?foo=bar?foo=bar`. Using `$uri` seems to work as intended, though there may be better options.

Comment: Adding ? after $request_uri will avoid repeated query string problem.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon after server_name