# Nginx user subdomains, should I proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, proxypass

I am trying to setup user subdomains, serving content from specific folders: `www.example.com/username` served from `username.example.com` (just like github pages).

I've looked at Nginx rewrites, but I don't want the browser to redirect--I want the domain to be username.example.com.
Anyway, a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498712/nginx-subdomain-rewrite) says that I cannot rewrite host, only proxy to it.
I tried to setup a `proxy_pass`, but all of the documentation and examples show it being used to (obviously) proxy to a service on another host or port, but in my case I want to just proxy to another location on the same host and port.

Is this the appropriate way to tackle this problem, and if so, what is the right Nginx config syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should almost work:

```
server {
  location / {
    # simple version
    if ( $host ~ "user1.example.com" ) {
      proxy_pass http://example.com/user1;
    }

    # generic version
    if ( $host ~ ^(.+)\.example\.com$ ) {
      proxy_pass http://example.com/$1;
    }


  }
}
```

But I doubt it will work as expected because of the "/user1" part in the proxied url, I am not sure of the consequences though.

Another way of doing this which will surely work is to either serve all the applications with the same nginx server or assign a given port to each of the other nginx.
Here is how I would do this:

```
server {
  location / {

    if ( $host ~ "user1.example.com" ) {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    if ( $host ~ "user2.example.com" ) {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
  }
}
```

Last time I did this was for a college project and I used a specific plugin to handle it, there may also be some plugin which can do this for nginx but I did not found any after a quick search.