# NGINX wildcard rewrite in same server block

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, rule

I cannot find an example of the specific rewrite rule im attempting.

I would like to have a rewrite rule for only subdomains entered for example.

https://sub.example.com/ -> https://example.com/directory1/directory2/sub

From what ive been trying this looks like the closest code i have got.

```
server_name example.com;

if ($host = *.example.com) 
    return 301 https://example.com/directory1/directory2/$1;   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx subdomain rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498712/nginx-subdomain-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs:

- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/if

---

This would be one solution:

```
server_name .example.com;
if ($host ~ ^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$) {
    return 301 http://example.com/directory1/directory2/$sub;
}
```

---

This would be another solution:

```
server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$;
return 301 http://example.com/directory1/directory2/$sub;
```

---

Which solution is better?  It's hard to tell — it depends on the patterns of the traffic you receive, as well as on what other servers are configured on the same listen handle.

Comment: The above works perfect, i tried to change it a rewrite instead of a return so that i dont get ssl certificate not valid for subdomain. Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Comment: I don't think you should be using rewrite here (if you need the request URI, use `$request_uri`); but there's no difference either way for SSL; you obviously have to have proper certs for all subdomains for this to work without a warning (or just don't use SSL!).